# PHP FetchAll to array

Tags: php

I'm trying to take a result from fetchAll and to take some of the data and put it into an array.

Relevant PHP:

```
  $catcodessql = "select distinct cat_code from mytable";
  $result2 = $dbh->query($catcodessql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This returns something like below:

```
array(4) {
 [0]=>
array(1) {
["cat_code"]=>
string(3) "edu"
 }
 [1]=>
 array(1) {
["cat_code"]=>
string(3) "inc"
}
[2]=>
array(1) {
["cat_code"]=>
string(3) "net"
 }
[3]=>
 array(1) {
["cat_code"]=>
string(3) "occ"
}
```

What I want is all those strings so I can dynamically put together this line later in my PHP:

```
$allcategories = array ('edu', 'inc', 'net', 'occ' );
```

So, I need to create a variable that will replace this part: `'edu', 'inc', 'net', 'occ'`

I've tried a couple of `while` functions, but clearly they aren't right.

Comment: If you use PHP +5.5 then you may want to look into: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: do you want only this array `$allcategories = array ('edu', 'inc', 'net', 'occ' )`?

Comment: @acontell Yes, that's what I want

Comment: check my answer below then, I think it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to retrieve unique categories, You can do it directly with a query:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select GROUP_CONCAT( cat_code SEPARATOR ',') as cat_code from ( select distinct cat_code from mytable) as m"); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$categories = explode(",",$row["cat_code"]);
var_dump($categories);
```

Comment: This results in roughly the same thing I had before: `array(36) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "edu"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "inc"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "net"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "occ"
  [4]=>`

Comment: isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: Ideally, I wanted it precisely in this format: `('edu', 'inc', 'net', 'occ' )`. I can't seem to get from the array returned to the array I need to feed another function, which just wants this comma separated list.

Comment: I mean, you need a string?

Comment: Wait a minute...my mistake. I actually don't need any further processing. I was able to take exactly what you had and put it into my function. So, this worked perfectly after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

```
$allcategories = array_column($result2, 'cat_code');
```

Or `foreach` over the `query`:

```
foreach($dbh->query($catcodessql) as $row) {
    $allcategories = $row['cat_code'];
}
```

Comment: If he only have this column in the array he also could use this one: `print_r(array_keys(call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map("array_flip", $arr))));` :D But i know that you love `array_column()`, so +1

Comment: I think I'm not implementing what you suggested correctly. I'm trying this:

`$catcodessql = "select distinct cat_code from mytable";

$dbh->query($catcodessql);

while($row = $dbh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $allcategories = $row['cat_code'];
}`

Is that right or am I missing something? This is returning a 500 error.

Comment: I don't know about the 500 and rarely use `query` but check the edit with the `foreach`.